# making a vertical line before text when hovered

Tags: html, css

I have created a list and when I hover a line should be displayed like this

[image]

See when hovered over Mobile & Tablets a vertical line is shown with orange color at the beginning

This is my simple code

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Umm yess. sorry a little too distracted in css

Comment: So, you evidently know how to change the *background* when the item is hovered... why not just `border-left: 2px solid orange;` on hover as well?

Comment: On hover state give it a border left  of 3 or 4px

Comment: @Santi my frontend developer is having fever so I am doing his stuff to complete the projects :D he's pro at css me pro in laravfel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give your the result as shown in the example:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: solid 1px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 1px transparent;
  border-left: solid 6px transparent;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border-top-color: grey;
  border-bottom-color: grey;
  border-left-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have different possibilities to solve this. You can try the following solutions:

**solution using [`box-shadow`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-box-shadow):**

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
}
li {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left:5px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-top:1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:1px solid transparent;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow:inset 3px 0px 0px 0px red;
  border-top-color:grey;
  border-bottom-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
</ul>
```

**solution using [`border-left`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-shorthands):**

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
}
li {
  border-left:3px solid transparent;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left:5px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-top:1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:1px solid transparent;
}
li:hover {
  border-left-color:red;
  background-color: white;
  border-top-color:grey;
  border-bottom-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
</ul>
```

**solution using [`linear-gradient`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#linear-gradients):**

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
}
li {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left:5px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-top:1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:1px solid transparent;
}
li:hover {
  background:linear-gradient(to right, red 0px, red 3px, transparent 3px);
  background-color: white;
  border-top-color:grey;
  border-bottom-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Getting creative with `linear-gradient`!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add a thick orange border to the left side of the li element on hover:

```css
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
li {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: grey;
}
li:hover {
    background-color: white;
    border-left: 5px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: May I make a suggestion? Prevent the text from shifting to the right.

Comment: Ah, I missed the transparent border-left, which is nicely shown by Sebastian's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Include a border from the beginning and then change it to the color you need.

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-left-width: 5px;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: lightgray;
  border-left-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can give padding and a border for the same

```
li:hover
{
  background-color: white;
  border-left: 5px solid orange;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This will shift the text around if applied to only the hover state.

Comment: yes... if we remove  padding-left from hover and apply it to `li` then it wont... also padding left has been added to match the image in the question

Comment: [**It still shifts**](https://jsfiddle.net/v1axp0v7/). There's no border on the `li` to begin with. Adding to only `hove`r will continue to shift the text.

Comment: That's much better! Update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is just add below CSS to your li:hover field,

```
li:hover{
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    border-left: 3px solid orange;
    background-color: white;
    color: orange;
}
```

Comment: This will shift the text around if applied to only the hover state. `text` isn't a CSS property.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a css ::before pseudo-element. See code snippet.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
}

li:hover::before {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: orange;
  top: 0;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
</ul>
```